# Bluetooth isn't working - fedora 24

Tags: fedora, mouse, bluetooth

I am dealing with a rather strange problem.
I've updated my fedora 24 system and after that my bluetooth Mouse (Microsoft Designers Mouse) stoped working.

Although the device seems connected, it seems that it's not trusted, as you can see bellow

```
[astamato@pcen35240 ~]$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller E4:B3:18:1E:2D:3B pcen35240 [default]
[NEW] Device E9:A1:2D:11:63:C4 Designer Mouse
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service000e
    0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Service
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service000e/char000f
    00002a19-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Battery Level
[NEW] Descriptor
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service000e/char000f/desc0011
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service0009
    0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Device Information
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service0009/char000c
    00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    PnP ID
[NEW] Characteristic
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service0009/char000a
    00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Manufacturer Name String
[NEW] Primary Service
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_E9_A1_2D_11_63_C4/service0008
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
[Designer Mouse]# info E9:A1:2D:11:63:C4
Device E9:A1:2D:11:63:C4
    Name: Designer Mouse
    Alias: Designer Mouse
    Appearance: 0x03c2
    Icon: input-mouse
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v045Ep0805d0110
```

In the meatime I've managed to make it trusted bu using

```
trust E9:A1:2D:11:63:C4
```

but it seems that this is not the problem... So the mouse is connected, it's paired (not always though), it is trusted but it cannot function...

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't resolve the issue. What solved it was to upgrade from `fedora 24` to `fedora 25`. I guess it had to do with an update on the bluetooth.